# Break bash array into pairs, and match on either element

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash script which loops through a list of arrays by 2 at a time, like this;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
    "apple" "fruit"
    "lettuce" "vegetables"
    "almonds" "nuts"
)

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2)); do
    echo "${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]}"
done
```

and when you run this script, it prints out;

```
apple fruit
lettuce vegetables
almonds nuts
```

I'm looking for a way to select a specific item from the array and only print that one, something like this;

```
./script.sh apple
```

and it will print out only the apple and the 2nd item with the apple;

```
apple fruit
```

or it can be the other way, like; `./script.sh fruit` and it will print out;

```
apple fruit
```

and if no arguments given, just print out everything.

So I'm basically looking for a way to choose items from the array, is this possible to do with bash arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as the simplest possible thing, taking your exact existing logic and just adding a conditional around the print operation:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
    "apple" "fruit"
    "lettuce" "vegetables"
    "almonds" "nuts"
)

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2)); do
    if [[ ${arr[i]} = "$1" ]] || [[ ${arr[i+1]} = "$2" ]]; then
        echo "${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]}"
    fi
done
```

---

However, if in your real-world use case you're going to be doing several invocations within the same script, it'll be worth the overhead to build a lookup table:

```
# initial setup, only needs to happen once
declare -a arr=(
    "apple" "fruit"
    "lettuce" "vegetables"
    "almonds" "nuts"
)
declare -A arrayFwd arrayRev
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2)); do
    arrayFwd[${arr[i]}]=${arr[i+1]}
    arrayRev[${arr[i+1]}]=${arr[i]}
done

lookup() {
  if [[ ${arrayFwd[$1]} ]]; then
    echo "$1 ${arrayFwd[$1]}"
  elif [[ ${arrayRev[$1]} ]]; then
    echo "${arrayRev[$1]} $1"
  fi
}
```

...after which you can cheaply run:

```
lookup apple
```

or

```
lookup fruit
```

...and performance will be identical no matter how many items are in the lookup table.

Comment: Thank you, this simply works. However, I forgot to mention that if no $@ given, simply print out everything?

Comment: Then check whether `(( $# == 0 ))` is true, and put your print-out-everything logic there.

Comment: thanks again, sounds like it'll do the job. But I didn't understand your 2nd script, I've tried running it but it simply does, nothing? or am I missing something? what should I expect when I run `lookup apple`?

Comment: So, the `lookup apple` needs to be inside the same script. Or you can use `source thescript` (where `thescript` is the name of the file you saved it in) to run it in your interactive shell so it defines the function (and the variables it uses) there.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/rbOQVC, doing three separate `lookup` calls after running the definitions through once.

Comment: if I have tens of arrays, then will I need to add all of them as lookup at the bottom of the script?

Comment: The `lookup` calls at the bottom are just that, *calls*. They demonstrate how to use the function, and show that it works (by generating output in the ideone.com example); that's their only purpose.

Comment: ...that said, if you want to dynamically build lookup tables, that's a job for namevars (aka indirect references). See [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006), paying close attention to the parts discussing `declare -n`.

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of a simple test to ensure you are (1) not matching the last element and (2) the current element equals the input parameter, you can output the *current* and *next* elements in the array with:

**updated to output all if no positional parameter provided**

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
    "apple" "fruit"
    "lettuce" "vegetables"
    "almonds" "nuts"
)

declare -i nelem=${#arr[@]}

for ((i = 0; i< nelem; i++)); do
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then    ## no argument given - output all
        echo "${arr[i]}"
    else
        ## test not last element and current equals input
        [ "$i" -lt $((nelem - 1)) ] && [ "${arr[i]}" = "$1" ] &&
        echo "${arr[i]} ${arr[$((i+1))]}"
    fi
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash a.sh apple
apple fruit

$ bash a.sh lettuce
lettuce vegetables

$ bash a.sh almonds
almonds nuts

$ bash a.sh nuts
(no output)
```

No input case:

```
$ bash a.sh
apple
fruit
lettuce
vegetables
almonds
nuts
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: `-a` is marked obsolescent (the first step towards being deprecated). Prefer `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` for best-practice POSIX sh compatibility instead. (Not that POSIX sh compatibility is attainable in the context of a script that deals with arrays)

Comment: Old habits die hard. Updated.

Comment: Also, `(( ... ))` is better for numeric comparisons.

Comment: True, my thought there is that for a new users stringing `((...)) && [....] && ...` together gets a bit confusing -- but I agree with you.

Comment: Might also add quotes to your `echo`.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy - that was a lazy omission.

Comment: BTW, isn't the correct output when the user says `nuts` the string `almonds nuts`, as opposed to the empty output this presently provides?

Comment: Thank you too! Once again, I forgot to mention that if no $@ given, then simply print out everything from the array as usual.

Comment: @MarryJane, ...adding new requirements after you already have answers makes something what's known as a "chameleon question"; they tend to be frowned on here. If you didn't include something in the question, but that question was still self-contained and useful enough to attract answers that were correct for it as-asked, it's more appropriate to ask a new question focused only on the remaining piece with all unrelated elements removed (if, of course, it's not already in the knowledge-base elsewhere).

Comment: got it, sorry about that. I'll be more careful on this. thank ya'll again! you guys been very helpful.